# Recursive Search on 2D grid

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, data-structures, depth-first-search

I implemented this to solve a problem and it works but if I try a bigger board, say 100x100 then it gets super slow and eventually crashes. I am asking for an insight on how I can improve it to search faster. I am trying to find all the words on the board that match given a length N. The words to match need to be of min length N and to be in the lexicon. I’m not sure how to implement this in another way. I’ve tried different variations and they all seem slow. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

```
public SortedSet<String> getWordsThatMatch(int minimumWordLength) {
  if (minimumWordLength < 1) {
     throw new IllegalArgumentException();
  }

  if (!lexiconLoaded) {
     throw new IllegalStateException();
  }

  SortedSet<String> result = new TreeSet<>();
  int n = board.length;

  for (int row = 0; row < n; row++) {
     for (int col = 0; col < n; col++) {
        StringBuilder currentWord = new StringBuilder();
        boolean[][] visited = new boolean[n][n];
        dfs(row, col, currentWord, visited, result, minimumWordLength);
     }
  }
  return result;
 }

 private void dfs(int row, int col, StringBuilder currentWord, boolean[][] visited,
                SortedSet<String> result, int minimumWordLength) {

  int n = board.length;

  if (row < 0 || col < 0 || row >= n || col >= n || visited[row][col]) {
     return;
  }

  if (currentWord.length() >= minimumWordLength && !isValidPrefix(currentWord.toString())) {
     return;
  }

  currentWord.append(board[row][col]);
  visited[row][col] = true;

  String word = currentWord.toString();

  if (word.length() >= minimumWordLength && isValidWord(word)) {
     result.add(word);
  }

  for (int dr = -1; dr <= 1; dr++) {
     for (int dc = -1; dc <= 1; dc++) {
        if (dr != 0 || dc != 0) {
           int newRow = row + dr;
           int newCol = col + dc;
           if (newRow >= 0 && newRow < n && newCol >= 0 && newCol < n) {
              dfs(newRow, newCol, new StringBuilder(currentWord), visited, result, minimumWordLength);
           }
        }
     }
  }
  
  visited[row][col] = false;
  }
```

Comment: Why does it crash?  Out of Memory, or what? I was thinking the question might be appropriate for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) But, Code Review wants questions about code that doesn't crash.  Would they make an exception for out of memory??

Comment: it was out of memory error :/

Comment: Question needs details, whether for here or code review. Can you give some examples with reasonably small boards? How is `board` declared? Is it `board [][] char` or what?  What does `isValidPrefix (String s)` supposed to do? Check the lexicon?

Comment: It looks like the letters of a valid word do not have to all be in a line. The letters could be on a path that turns several times. Is that correct?

Comment: Could you simply obtain matches of the regular expression `\S{4,}` (which will match words having at least 4 non-whitespace characters) and then filter those with `isValidWord` (which I assume is a dictionary lookup)? Alternatively, match `[a-zA-Z]{4,}`, assuming characters are either letters or spaces. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/djyRoI/1)